# FromXYZ vs Overloaded Method

Tags: c#, refactoring, coding-style

I'm trying to think of the cleanest way to implement a couple of methods that open a file.

Consider the following method signatures:

```
public static DomainObject Load(Uri urlToFile)
{
    /* downloads file and calls Load(savedToFilename) */
}

public static DomainObject Load(string filename) 
{ 
    /* creates filestream and calls Load(stream) */
}

public static DomainObject Load(Stream stream) 
{ 
    /* does actual loading */ 
}
```

I'm trying to implement some concepts from [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882), specifically:

> When constructors are overloaded, use static factory methods with names that describe the arguments. For example,
>
> *Complex fulcrumPoint = Complex.FromRealNumber(23.0);*
>
> is generally better than
>
> *Complex fulcrumPoint = new Complex(23.0);*

Now, I know I do not have overloaded constructors, per se (I refactored away from that), but I think the principle is the same. So that implies that my Load methods be refactored to something like:

```
public static DomainObject FromURI(Uri urlToFile);
public static DomainObject FromFile(string filename);
public static DomainObject FromStream(Stream stream);
```

But, tbh, I think it's more intuitive to use what I've already got. From a consumer's perspective it feels like Open will take whatever source I happen to have whereas the other method requires me to think first about what my source is and then wonder if there is a specific method for that.

So I ask, from your more experienced viewpoint, which is better and why?

Comment: I would consider `Clean Code`s method bloat. I can see that 23 is a real number; why do I need the method name to say that?

Comment: I agree with mathepic that it does seem like code bloat. I would say it may be valid if you work in a language which doesn't have a de facto IDE (i.e. PHP vs. C# & Visual Studio), or if the IDE doesn't support intellisense. However, if intellisense is supported or offered, then I'm typically OK with overloaded factory methods, since they can indicate what the type of the expected parameter(s) and their names should be representative of their use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think "Load" is the way to go for a few reasons:

- The parameter type is already in the parameter list- why specify it again in the method name?
- If you happen to have multiple methods that produce something a stream in a class, "FromStream" becomes a problem.
- In the age of intellisense, it's much more logical to type "Load" and get a list of possible parameter options, rather than look at three different methods (especially if more methods than just those in this set happen to start with "From").
- Another decent rule of thumb is "name methods after verbs when you can," which votes in favor of something akin to "Load," or at least "LoadFrom..."

Comment: Totally! And not to mention, it's so much cooler to say "method overloads".

Comment: +1 for good answer. Also, all methods exhibit the same behaviour and return the same result; as such, it's better to overload the method as it makes this point clear to the programmer (you, in this case). If you use slightly different names, the programmer might get confused. Finally, "FromXYZ" doesn't tell you what the method _does_, but "Load" does (well, maybe it could be named even better, but it's vastly better than "FromXYZ" at least). Always strive for self-commenting code.

Comment: @gablin: The name `FromXYZ` tells me exactly what the method should do: construct a new instance using information contained in an XYZ.  By contrast, `Load` does not indicate whether it should modify an existing instance by replacing its contents with data from the indicated source, combine its contents with the source, or perhaps create a new object which has some properties of the existing object and incorporates data from the indicated source.

Comment: @supercat: I'd agree that `Load` on its own is a bit vague, but `loadFrom` should convey the same semantics as `FromXYZ` whilst avoiding the name repetition which is already part of the function argument. Moreover, the information of whether the input arguments are modified or not should be made clear through the use of `const`.

Comment: @gablin: In many cases, it's possible for a single *type* to be capable of holding many *kinds* of things. For example, a string may hold either the name of a local text file, a URL identifying a remote text file, or a quantity of text which should be interpreted as the contents of such a file. While it would be possible to require that the string be an URL, I think `fromFile(theName)` is cleaner than `loadFrom(URLFormatter.fileNameToURL(theName))`.  Also, the question wouldn't be whether the *input* arguments are modified, but rather...

Comment: @gablin: ...how (if at all) a method call like `myDocument.loadFrom(fileName);` should affect the contents of `myDocument`, in either the success or failure cases.  Although C++ would allow a method to indicate that it doesn't modify the instance upon which it is invoked, C# has no such feature.